# program to print directory structure recursively in python not working

Tags: python, recursion, os.path

I have this directory structure:

```
test1
   file1.txt
   test2
       file2.txt
       test3
           file3.txt
           test4
                file4.txt
```

my current code to print this directory levels is as follows:

```
    import os
    def printRootStructure(dirname,indent=0):
        for i in range(indent):
            print "   ",
        print dirname
        if os.path.isdir(dirname):
            for files in os.listdir(dirname):
                printRootStructure(files,indent+1)


    printRootStructure("test")
```

It currently prints as

```
test
    file1.txt
    test1
```

It is not proceeding to next level. any help here to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix this by passing the full path name into `printRootStructure`:

```
import os
def printRootStructure(dirname,indent=0):
    for i in range(indent):
        print "   ",
    print os.path.basename(dirname) # changed
    if os.path.isdir(dirname):
        for files in os.listdir(dirname):
            printRootStructure(os.path.join(dirname,files),indent+1) # changed
```

As it was in your original code, you were passing just the last part (this is called the "basename") of each file into `printRootStructure` when you made the recursive calls.

#### Working directory and path names

Any time you start up a program on a modern computer, your program runs in a fixed location in the filesystem (this is called the "current working directory"). If you invoke a program from the commane-line, the current working directory is simply the path where you invoked the program's name. If you invoke a program by clicking something in a GUI environment, it can get more complicated, but the general behavior is the same: your program always runs in a specific working directory.

All path tests, and in particular [`os.path.isdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), are evaluated with respect to that working directory. So when you make your first recursive call in your example, you are testing `os.path.isdir("test1")`, which doesn't exist in the working directory -- it only exists inside "test" !

The fix is to pass the full path name into your recursive calls. Then, because your full name might be excessive when you print out the tree, I added a call to [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to print just the basename portion of each file.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a specific reason to use recursion, it's simpler to use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse a directory structure.

```
import os
import os.path as P
for topdir, subdirs, files in os.walk(starting_point):
  print "    " * topdir.count(P.sep), P.basename(topdir)
  for f in sorted(files):
    print "    " * (topdir.count(P.sep) + 1), f
```